# How to fix the white screen drawing error?

Tags: java

I'm new to Stackoverflow and tried to follow the rules as much as possible. I haven't been able to solve this problem for hours. When I start the program it **seldom** starts strangely:
properly started: correct image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc0Hk.png]

not properly started: white screen:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gesKX.png]

If you see an error in the code and help me fix it I would appreciate it. any correction

---

```
public class MainClass extends JPanel implements Runnable, MouseListener {
    enum MenuState {
        xMenu1, xMenu2;
    }

    private MenuState menuState = MenuState.xMenu1;
    JFrame frame;
    private Image bgImage, playButtonImage, backButtonImage;
    private Rectangle playButton, backButton;

    
    public MainClass() {
        frame = new JFrame("TEST");
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.addMouseListener(this);
        frame.add(this);
        try {
            bgImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Data/background.png"));
            playButtonImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Data/playButton2.png"));
            backButtonImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Data/backButton.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        playButton = new Rectangle(900, 400, 214, 78);
        backButton = new Rectangle(5, 5, 136, 92);

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        System.out.println("thread started");
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainClass();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("run method started");
            if (menuState == menuState.xMenu1) {

            } else if (menuState == menuState.xMenu2) {

            }
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (menuState == menuState.xMenu1) {
            g.drawImage(playButtonImage, playButton.x, playButton.y, this); // THIS IS THE 77th LINE
        } else if (menuState == menuState.xMenu2) {
            g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, this);
            g.drawImage(backButtonImage, backButton.x, backButton.y, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (menuState == menuState.xMenu1) {
            if (playButton.intersects(e.getX(), e.getY(), 1, 1)) {
                menuState = menuState.xMenu2;
            }
        } else if (menuState == menuState.xMenu2) {
            if (backButton.intersects(e.getX(), e.getY(), 1, 1)) {
                menuState = menuState.xMenu1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for a working example of custom painting which will give you program better structure. 1) the frame should not be created in the constructor of your class, 2) the GUI should be created on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. There is no need for a Thread.

Comment: @camickr ok thanks for help. Custom painting is too complicated for me but i am trying.